# Trigger to update values from one object to other object

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 2 Custom objects

1. Product
2. L1-l4 Master (Relationship - unrelated to each other)

Both have common fields = L1,l2,L3,L4,Craft,Origin,Fabric,Zari type

Scenario: When Product is created, trigger should update L1-L4 (Active) values from L1-l4 Master object in the Product object.

Please find the code below:

```apex
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
        List<L1_L5_Master__c> L1_L5_Values = new List<L1_L5_Master__c>();
           L1_L5_Values = [SELECT id,Craft__c,Fabric__c,Origin__c,Zari_Type__c,L1__c,L2__c,L3__c,L4__c from L1_L5_Master__c WHERE Active__c=True];
        for(Product__c allProdValues:Trigger.new){
            if(allProdValues.Workmanship__c = L1_L5_Values.Craft__c && allProdValues.Cluster__c = L1_L5_Values.Origin__c && allProdValues.Fabric__c = L1_L5_Values.Fabric__c && allProdValues.Zari_Type__c = L1_L5_Values.Zari_Type__c){
                allProdValues.L1__c = L1_L5_Values.L1__c;
                allProdValues.L2__c = L1_L5_Values.L2__c;
                allProdValues.L3__c = L1_L5_Values.L3__c;
                allProdValues.L4__c = L1_L5_Values.L4__c;
            }
        }
        if(allProdValues.size()>0){
            UPDATE allProdValues;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to be addressed here:

1. It's better to set the values of fields in before insert as I don't see any id's of the records created being used to fetch other records. This will save you from performing any DML operations.
2. **L1_L5_Values** is a list, so you can't just use **L1_L5_Values.Craft__c** as these fields exist on the individual object record instead of the list of objects. You'll have to iterate through the list and then compare it with the product fields.

```
if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
    List<L1_L5_Master__c> L1_L5_ValueList = new List<L1_L5_Master__c>();
    L1_L5_ValueList = [SELECT id, Craft__c, Fabric__c, Origin__c, Zari_Type__c, L1__c, L2__c, L3__c, L4__c from L1_L5_Master__c WHERE Active__c = True];
    for(Product__c productRec : Trigger.new){
        String prodKey = productRec.Workmanship__c + productRec.Cluster__c + productRec.Fabric__c + productRec.Zari_Type__c;
        for (L1_L5_Master__c L1_L5_Value : L1_L5_ValueList) {
            String masterKey = L1_L5_Value.Craft__c + L1_L5_Value.Origin__c + L1_L5_Value.Fabric__c + L1_L5_Value.Zari_Type__c;
            if(prodKey == masterKey){
                productRec.L1__c = L1_L5_Value.L1__c;
                productRec.L2__c = L1_L5_Value.L2__c;
                productRec.L3__c = L1_L5_Value.L3__c;
                productRec.L4__c = L1_L5_Value.L4__c;
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

This is a link to some of the best practices for Apex: [apex best practices](https://www.salesforceben.com/12-salesforce-apex-best-practices/). I hope this will be of some help.

Comment: Thank you so much Chandrashekaran for your kind help.